# ajax clicked button and form values

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a single form and each item has an add button. I would just like to submit the form data to a php script that processes the ajax, and also know which add button is being clicked on. I'm not seeing the clicked ID of the button in the post on the ajax page, so I'm trying to attach it to the serialized data using event.target. I see the clicked ID in the first alert. The email is sending from the process page, but there is no id in the post data, and the ajax response success alert isn't popping up.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or is there a better way?

```
<form name="callback_form" id="callback_form" method="post">
    <input name="num1" type="text" value="num1val">
    <select name="sel1" id="sel1">
    <option value="sel1val1">sel1val</option>
    <option value="sel1val2">sel1val2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" name="add1" id="add1" onclick="addToCart(event)">add Item 1</button> 

    <input name="num2" type="text" value="num2val">
    <select name="sel2" id="sel2">
    <option value="sel2val1">sel2val1</option>
    <option value="sel2val2">sel2val2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" name="add2" id="add2" onclick="addToCart(event)">add item 2</button> 
</form>

<script>
function addToCart(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      var id = event.target.id;  
      var dataString = $(this).serialize()+'&id='+id;
      alert(dataString);

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_ajax.php",
        data: $('#callback_form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,       
        success: function(response)
        {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);

        if (jsonData.success == "1")
            alert(1);
        }    
    }); 
}
</script>
```

process_ajax.php

```
$post=print_r($_POST,1);
mail('myemail@gmail.com','-'.post.'-'.time().'-',$post);
echo json_encode(array('success' => 1,'return_message' => 'yep'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are serializing form data, but not including the id param, try with:

```
function addToCart(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  var id = event.target.id;  
  var formData = $('#callback_form').serialize();
  var dataString = formData + '&id=' + id;
  alert(dataString);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process_ajax.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,       
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.success == "1") {
        alert(1);
      }
    }    
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank for your response. That has indeed fixed the first part of my issue and I now have the ID. Thank you! 
I'm still seeing the second issue though. The success alert is not popping up and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Well .. place `console.log(response)` right before if statement and post result here

Comment: thanks again, being logged is, {success: 1, return_message: 'yep'}

Comment: It looks like your success number is integer and you are cheking for string, try with `if (response.success == 1)`

Comment: That's it. It now works. Thank you for sticking with me and helping. I really appreciate it!